# При исправлении одной ошибки возникает сразу несколько других

Tags: c++, qt

Есть код, при исправлении одной ошибки возникает сразу несколько других. Помогите исправить их.

```
    #ifndef WIDGET_H
    #define WIDGET_H

    #include <QWidget>

    namespace Ui 
    {
    class Widget;
    }

    class Widget : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

    public slots:
    // функция последовательного выбора значений по возрастанию
    void lNext();

    // функция последовательного выбора значений по убыванию
    void lPrev();

    // функция удаления определенной позиции
    void lMut(int iNum);

    private slots:

    private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

    // объявляем список
    QList<int> mList;
};

   #endif // WIDGET_H

   // вывод значений из списка, по возрастанию

       void Widget::lNext()
       {
    // Объявляем класс работы над списком
    QListIterator<int> Iter(mList);

    // переходим к началу списка
    Iter.toFront();

    // цикл обработки каждой позиции
    while (Iter.hasNext())
    {
        // записываем значение в listWidget
        ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(Iter.next()));

        // проверяем установлена ли "птичка" на checkBox
        if(ui->checkBox->isChecked())
        {
            // если установлена
            if (Iter.hasNext())
                // выводим в listWidget информацию о сл. значении списка
                ui->listWidget->addItem("Следующее значение... " + QString::number(Iter.peekNext()));
        }
    }
}

    void Widget::lPrev()
    {
    QListIterator<int> Iter(mList);
    // переходим в конец списка
    Iter.toBack();
    // цикл вывода значений в обратном порядке
    while (Iter.hasPrevious())
    {
        ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(Iter.previous()));

        // "птичка" на checkBox
        if(ui->checkBox->isChecked())
        {
            if(Iter.hasPrevious())
              ui->listWidget->addItem("Следующее значение... " + QString::number(Iter.peekPrevious()));
        }
    }
}

    void Widget::lMut(int iNum)
    {
    // класс управления списком
    QMutableListIterator<int> Iter(mList);
    // переходим к началу списка
    Iter.toFront();
    // проходим по всем элементам списка
    while (Iter.hasNext())
    {
        // присваиваем переменной "i" значение списка
        int i = Iter.next();
        // проверяем на равенство значения в lineEdit
        if(i == iNum)
        {
            // если равно, то удаляем
            Iter.remove();
        }
    }
    // вызываем слот click() кнопки "Show"
    ui->pushButton->click();
}

    void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
    // кнопка "Show"

    // если выбран первый radioButton
    if (ui->radioButton->isChecked())
    {
        // очищаем listWidget
        ui->listWidget->clear();
        // запускаем функцию вывода значений из списка по возрастанию
        lNext();
    }
    // если выбран второй radioButton
    if (ui->radioButton_2->isChecked())
    {
        // очищаем listWidget
        ui->listWidget->clear();
        // запускаем функцию вывода значений из списка по убыванию
        lPrev();
    }
}

    void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
    {
    // Delete

    // проверяем есть ли запись в lineEdit
    if (ui->lineEdit->text() == "")
    {
        // если lineEdit пуст, то выводим предупреждающее значение
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Warning", "Вы не ввели значение для удаления! Перепроверьте данные!");
        // делаем активным lineEdit для ввода значения
        ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
        // останавливаем дальнейшее выполнение
        return;
    }
    // если lineEdit не пустое
    else
    {
        // очищаем listWidget
        ui->listWidget->clear();
        // создаем числовую переменную и переносим в нее данные из lineEdit
        int iNum = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
        // вызываем функцию удаления с аргументом
        lMut(iNum);
    }
}

    void Widget::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
    {
    // Refresh QList

    // Создадим еще один список(по умолчанию он пустой)
    QList<int> lTemp;

    // обнулим наш список, созданным
    mList = lTemp;
    // заполним его данными
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mList.append(i);
    }
    // очистим listWidget
    ui->listWidget->clear();

    // нажатие кнопки "Show" для вывода результата
    ui->pushButton->click();
}

   close();
```

Ошибки

> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\main.cpp:1:
> In file included from
> ..\project\main.cpp:1:0:
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:-1:
> In member function 'void
> Widget::lNext()':
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:53:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>          ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(Iter.next()));
>            ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:56:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>          if(ui->checkBox->isChecked())
>               ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:61:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>                  ui->listWidget->addItem("РЎР»РµРґСѓСЋС‰РµРµ
> Р·РЅР°С‡РµРЅРёРµ... " +
> QString::number(Iter.peekNext()));
>                    ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:-1:
> In member function 'void
> Widget::lPrev()':
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:74:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>          ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(Iter.previous()));
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:77:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>          if(ui->checkBox->isChecked())
>               ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:80:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>                ui->listWidget->addItem("РЎР»РµРґСѓСЋС‰РµРµ
> Р·РЅР°С‡РµРЅРёРµ... " +
> QString::number(Iter.peekPrevious()));
>                  ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:-1:
> In member function 'void
> Widget::lMut(int)':
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:104:
> ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type
> 'class Ui::Widget'
>      ui->pushButton->click();
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:8:
> ошибка: forward declaration of 'class
> Ui::Widget'  class Widget;
>        ^ C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:-1:
> At global scope:
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:107:
> ошибка: no 'void
> Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()'
> member function declared in class
> 'Widget'  void
> Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:129:
> ошибка: no 'void
> Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()'
> member function declared in class
> 'Widget'  void
> Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
>                                       ^
>
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\main.cpp:1:
> In file included from
> ..\project\main.cpp:1:0:
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:155:
> ошибка: no 'void
> Widget::on_pushButton_4_clicked()'
> member function declared in class
> 'Widget'  void
> Widget::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
>                                       ^
> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\project\widget.h:176:
> ошибка: expected constructor,
> destructor, or type conversion before
> ';' token  close();
>         ^

Answer (score 1):

Включите заголовок формы `(ui_Widget.h)` вначале.

Comment: С этим я уже разобралась, теперь возникли другие проблемы.